# Random order from YouTube /v3/search API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using the YouTube API V3 search endpoint, and the order of videos I get is seemingly random between refreshes. In some cases the videos will appear in the right order, and a couple of refreshes later the contents change.

I'm sorting by date, but it doesn't seem to do the trick. Here's an example of what I'm calling:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={API_KEY}&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&maxResults=18&part=snippet%2Cid&order=date`

For example, in one refresh I got a video uploaded a week ago first, and on the second one a video uploaded 3 weeks ago is first, with a random set of videos missing as if the return is not ordered at all.

Is this not the correct endpoint for this, or is there some sort of undocumented property to get things back in a consistent order? I've seen other posts complaining of a similar problem, but that seems to have been resolved as far back as 2019.

Comment: Can you provide the channel_id you're using, the current results and the desired results? - not doubting of your findings, but, if this behaviour was posted before, can you share the links of such posts?